# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context when trying to resolve a class

Tags: c#, autofac

I've been using Autofac for a while and it has worked flawlessly.

When I recently wanted to implement it in another project, I immediately encountered an exception that I have no idea why it occurs or where it could stem from.

> System.ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   context"

```
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context)
AssetManagement.App.Test.Main(String[] args) in Test.cs: line: 24
System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**App.cs**:

```
public class Test
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var scheduledJob = Startup.Container.Resolve<IScheduledJob>();   // Exception on this line
        }
}
```

**Startup.cs**:

```
internal static class Startup
{
        public static IContainer Container { get; private set; }


        public static void Run()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();


            builder.RegisterType<Test.ScheduledJobTest>().As<IScheduledJob>();


            Container = builder.Build();
        }
    }
```

The strange thing is that I'm getting this exception regardless if I've registered any components in `Startup` or not.

Another peculiar thing is that I'm getting the error regardless of which class I'm trying to resolve.

Same error is given to me with the following code:

```
var scheduledJob = Startup.Container.Resolve<Exception>();
```

Comment: Where are you calling `Startup.Run`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Resolve` methods in the stack trace are extension methods on the `IComponentContext` interface. It's at the `ResolveService` method that a check is made to ensure that the target of the extension method is actually not `null`. In your case the `Container` property must be `null` and probably hasn't been initialized because no call to the static `Run` method has been made.

I assume this is just some quick spike code to test something out, but if you take it further you should try to avoid holding a static reference to the container as it encourages the `Service Locator` [anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).